# setInteval vs setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, slideshow

As a follow up to this question: [Hover starts a simple slideshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104115/hover-starts-a-simple-slideshow)

Firefox behaves strange on if using the **setInteval** function:

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/F4peh/38/) and the script:

```
$('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
$(".fadein").hover(function() {
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
            .next('img').fadeIn()
            .end().appendTo('.fadein');
    }, 1000);
}, function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
});
```

This functions beautifully in Chrome, but when I open the fiddle in Firefox and hover over the image for a bit, events start bubbling up and don't stop on mouse leave.

**EDIT:**

Funny story - I changed some parameters and it works in Firefox, but not in Chrome.
I changed the **setInterval** function with **setTimeout**. See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F4peh/143/):

```
$('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
$('.fadein').mouseenter(function(){
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn()
        .end().appendTo('.fadein');
    }, 1000);
}) .mouseleave(function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

So the bottom line is - it still doesn't work as it should.

Comment: Did any of the answer on your last question solve that issue? maybe you should select an answer from the previous question? Where is your `mouseleave` event handling?

Comment: it wasn't my question and I couldn't comment on it, so I've opened this one. Just try the jsfiddle in Chrome and in Firefox and you will see them react very differently, namely the events bubbling up in Firefox, but not in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to see if timer exists before setting it.

```
$(".fadein").hover(function(){
    if (timer) { clearInterval(timer); }
    timer = setInterval(function(){
```

Comment: Maybe. Can you please test it in jsfiddle if it works in firefox, I can't make it work.